# iOS Create Button with two separate labels

Tags: ios, uibutton

I would like create a button with two independent labels. 
I want to set in one button, two separate texts in different colors. 
e.g.

```
[myButton setTitle: @"Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
[myButton setTitle2: @"Title2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is it even possible? Maybe I should need to create a new control? Can anyone help me? I will be very grateful for a tutorial step by step.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and for my English. Forgive me that perhaps my description of the problem was not clear. 

Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, you can do this :

```
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40);
[self.view addSubview:testButton];

UILabel *firstLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
firstLineTestButton.text = @"First line";
firstLineTestButton.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[testButton addSubview:firstLineTestButton];

UILabel *secondLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 20)];
secondLineTestButton.text = @"Second line";
secondLineTestButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[testButton addSubview:secondLineTestButton];
```

but the @vikingosegundo's solution is more appropriate for the new SDK

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i need. Two separate labels. Thank you for your example. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to do it all in Interface Builder you could place two UILabels where you want them in the view and then lay a UIButton over the top of them. Then with the Attributes Inspector change the UIButton's type to "Custom" and delete any existing label or placeholder text it has. This will make the button clear so both labels show through and you can set the UIButton's IBAction to do whatever you want to the two separate UILabels.

Comment: If you do this, make sure you add an Accessibility Label to the button to help those who are visually impaired, and to help you write UI tests. Also, don't forget to write UI tests.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 6 and higher you can use `setAttributedTitle:forState:` to set an attributes string. A NSAttributedString can have many different attributes like text color.

Comment: This would allow him to apply multiple styles to a single button label. It would not allow him to have multiple independent labels.  Of course, the question isn't really clear about what he's actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Version:**

The following code also centres two titles both horizontally and vertically inside the button and has some font style adjustments.

```
let lineOne = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.button.frame.size.height / 4, width: self.button.frame.size.width, height: self.button.frame.size.height / 4))
lineOne.text = "Title 1"
lineOne.textColor = .black
lineOne.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
lineOne.textAlignment = .center
                
let lineTwo = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: lineOne.frame.size.height * 2, width: self.button.frame.size.width, height: self.button.frame.size.height / 4))
lineTwo.text = "Title 2"
lineTwo.textColor = .black
lineTwo.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
lineTwo.textAlignment = .center

self.button.addSubview(lineOne)
self.button.insertSubview(lineTwo, belowSubview: lineOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`. So you can add two different labels to your button using `- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view`.  Positioning could then be done either with Autolayout (if you are using that), or frames + springs/struts.